# ¿Como obtener las funciones asociadas a un evento de un elemento con jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenos dias, la consulta es sencilla pero no logro llegar a un método mas directo para obtener la las funciones asociadas a un elemento,

Supongamos que tenemos una etiqueta button y al evento click le asociamos la función Saludo, seria algo asi:

```
$('button').on('click', Saludo);
```

Ahora supongamos que al evento click de ese boton tambien se le asocian dos funciones mas, Despedida y Llegada.

```
 $('button').on('click', Despedida);
 $('button').on('click', Llegada);
```

Pero estas asociaciones son dinámicas, como haría para comprobar si, por ejemplo, la función Despedida, esta asociada o no? Estaba pensando en algún tipo de condicional pero no se como obtener si la función Despedida esta aplicada a este button o no....

Comment: Crea una cuarta función que seleccione entre las otras 3 mediante algún parámetro dado, si son dinámicas puedes usar la función `eval` para crear el código dinámico. Asociarlas como propones me parece mala practica, porque nunca sabes cual se ejecutara o el orden.

Comment: Tendrías que valerte de las herramientas de administrador. La discusión en este tema siempre es la misma, JS no te dará una lista exacta y precisa de todos los eventos asociados a un elemento HTML, esto más que nada por la forma en como dichos eventos son asociados dependiendo de cómo hayan sido registrados (jQuery, librerías, inlineJS, vanilla JS, etc...)

Comment: Lo que coloque es solo un ejemplo, la cosa es que estoy clonando un div y todos sus elementos hijos, en el proceso modifico cosas como id y nombres pero necesito hay un elemento, el cual es una etiqueta <a> que necesito  que tengo una funcion asociada y cuando copia me copia la funcion del original, y eso esta bien, pero hay un caso que me funciona y otro no, necesito que me agrege siempre una funcion entre dos que tengo... pero si le quito una funcion y le agrego la que quiero, me ejecuta dos veces la misma funcion y no es lo que quiero, esto es por que es un formulario dinamico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery te puede devolver los eventos relacionados a un elemento, pero solo de los que fueron puestos por el mismo jQuery, esa es la desventaja.

Pero si lo decides hacer con jQuery una posible solución seria esta:

```
function hola(){
    console.log('Hola');
}
function fnNew(){
    console.log('Esta es la nueva funcion');
}

$(document).on('click', hola);

var elemento = $(document)[0];

var indiceFn = $._data(elemento, 'events')['click'].findIndex(function(e){ 

    return e.handler.name === "hola"     
})

if (indiceFn !== -1) $._data(elemento, 'events')['click'][indiceFn].handler = fnNew;
```

De esta manera busca la funcion deseada (hola) y la sustituye por otra (fnNew). Si lo que quieres es solo copiar la funcion cuando la encuentre seria:

```
if (indiceFn !== -1) var copyFn = $._data(elemento, 'events')['click'][indiceFn].handler;
```